# Unable to run the application using docker swarm but same runs using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a web application inside docker.  Objective of the application is that whenever user makes a request, it should be routed through `nginx` to any of the application servers. Currently application holds 3 app servers and 3 database servers.  Following are the list of components inside the application:

```
1) MYSQLDB
2) MongoDB
3) RedisDB
4) Load Balancer (nginx)
5) Application Server (Running in Node.js built on top of socket.io)
```

Please find below the `docker-compose.yml` file which successfully creates the application environment:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  appserver1:
      container_name: appserver1
      depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "mongo"
      - "mariadb"
      build: ./application-module
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - /Volumes:/var/www/html/files
      command: bash -c "sleep 5 && forever app.js"
  appserver2:
      container_name: appserver2
      depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "mongo"
      - "mariadb"
      build: ./application-module
      tty: true
      volumes:
         - /Volumes:/var/www/html/files
      command: bash -c "sleep 10 && forever app.js"
  appserver3:
      container_name: appserver3
      depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "mongo"
      - "mariadb"
      build: ./application-module
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - /Volumes:/var/www/html/files
      command: bash -c "sleep 15 && forever app.js"
  adminserver:
      container_name: adminserver
      build: ./admin-module
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - ./var/www/html/files:/var/www/html/files     
  loadbalancer:
      container_name: loadbalancer
      build: ./load-balancer
      tty: true
      links:
          - appserver1
          - appserver2
          - appserver3
      ports:
          - '91:91'
  redis:
      container_name: redisdb
      build: ./redis
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - redisvolume:/data
  mongo:
      container_name: mongodb
      build: ./mongo
    #   environment:
    #       - http_proxy=$http_proxy
    #       - https_proxy=$https_proxy
    #       - no_proxy=$no_proxy
    #       - HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
    #       - HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY
    #       - NO_PROXY=$NO_PROXY
      volumes:
        - mongovolume:/data/db
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mariadbvolume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    # networks: 
    #  - overlay
    ports: 
    - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mys@l123'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=copconnect_dev'
      - 'MYSQL_USER=root'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=*****'
volumes:
 mariadbvolume:
 mongovolume:
 redisvolume:
 adminvolume:
 appvolume:
```

Please find below the `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

  server {
   listen 91;
   server_name localhost;

   location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://io_nodes;
            }
    }



    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
    }



  upstream io_nodes {
  ip_hash;

  server copconnect_appserver.1:3001;

  server copconnect_appserver.2:3001;

  server copconnect_appserver.3:3001;

  }
}
```

Upon running `docker-compose.yml` the application successfully creates the platform and runs the application but when I try to execute in the swarm mode it creates lots of problems - services are not getting created for loadbalancer & appserver.

Find the `docker-compose-stack.yml` file below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379"
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    volumes:
      - mariadbvolume:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    ports: 
    - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=copconnect_dev'
      - 'MYSQL_USER=root'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=********'
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports: 
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongovolume:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  appserver:
    image: localhost:5000/appserver:latest
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
         - ./var/www/html/files:/var/www/html/files
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
      - mariadb
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
      labels: [APP=appserver]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    stop_grace_period: 1m30s
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  loadbalancer:
    image: localhost:5000/nginx:1.0
    ports:
      - "91:91"
    stop_grace_period: 1m30s
    networks:
      - backend  
networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  mariadbvolume:
  mongovolume:
  redisvolume:
  appvolume:
```

Upon creation of swarm cluster and trying to run the application, it mentions in the logs that appserver is unable to connect to database. 
 The loadbalancer service is not turning up as it mentions that appserver.1,appserver.2,appserver.3 doesnt exist.